# DevExpress MVC controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I cannot seem to align the DevExpress controls in the Razor view. No matter what div and span combination I use, whenever I use @Html.DevExpress().TextBox the next controls always goes below. I want to display several labels and text boxes horizontally, one next to each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use recommendations from the [Possible ways of arranging DevExpress controls within a page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18357) KB Article to resolve this issue.